# Animate Marker Google Map android

Tags: android, maps, google-maps-markers

I have implemented google map in my application, I want to animate my marker like below.

How can I achieve this?

[image]

Comment: https://ddewaele.github.io/GoogleMapsV2WithActionBarSherlock/part3- hope you will found some intresting here

Comment: show your code for initializing map and pushing marker

Answer (score 1):

Check this link,https://github.com/aarsy/GoogleMapsAnimations

GoogleMapsAnimations" is an awesome first of its type android library for showing a ripple and radar animations on a google map, e.g show catchment area of an earthquake where ripples have been felt, give prominence to certain markers which need to be highlighted. Also add a ripple when your user is moving on the map and give a #PokemonGo type ripple effect and also add a radar type effect to show users that you are searching in certain area

Answer (score 0):

This link should help you :
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/marker
Then just use the image you have posted as the marker

Comment: i dont want to normal marker i want like above mentoned image @TheIronDuke

Comment: You just need to replace the normal one with a custom one which is cover in the page i liked , search for 'Customize a marker'